# Pass in ruby variable to a class factory ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My intention is to create custom error classes in various places for my Rails application since most of the error classes have the same methods. I have decided to create a YAML file to contain all the information from various error classes, and use a class factory script to generate all the classes in runtime. Here is what I have:

**chat_policy.rb**

```
class ChatPolicy; ... end

class ChatPolicy::Error < StandardError
  ERROR_CLASSES = GLOBAL_ERROR_CLASSES['chat_policy']
  ERROR_CLASSES.each do |cls|
  const_set(cls['class_name'], Class.new(ChatPolicy::Error) {
    attr_reader :object

    def initialize(object)
        @object = object
    end

    define_method(:message) do
        cls['message']
    end

    define_method(:code) do
        cls['code']
    end
  })
end
```

the `GLOBAL_ERROR_CLASSES` is loaded from YAML.load and turned to an object.

**error_classes.yml**

```
chat_policy:
- class_name: UserBlacklisted
  message: You are not allowed to do this
  code: ECP01
- class_name: UserSuspended
  message: You are not allowed to do this
  code: ECP02
- class_name: UserNotEligibleToRent
  message: You are not allowed to do this
  code: ECP03
- class_name: MembershipTierNotAllowed
  message: You are not allowed to do this
  code: ECP04
```

*** __ Question is __ ***

Now I have other files like `register_policy`, `checkout_policy`, `discount_policy` ..etc. It would be very duplicated if I have to do the class generation in every policy file. I wonder if I can shorten the code to something like this:

**chat_policy_intended.rb**

```
class ChatPolicy::Error < StandardError
  ERROR_CLASSES = GLOBAL_ERROR_CLASSES['chat_policy']
  error_class_factory(ChatPolicy::Error, ERROR_CLASSES)
end
```

**discount_policy_intended.rb**

```
class DiscountPolicy::Error < StandardError
  ERROR_CLASSES = GLOBAL_ERROR_CLASSES['discount_policy']
  error_class_factory(DiscountPolicy::Error, ERROR_CLASSES)
end
```

**error_clas_factory.rb**

```
ERROR_CLASSES.each do |cls|
const_set(cls['class_name'], Class.new(/*class_variable*/) {
    attr_reader :object

    def initialize(object)
        @object = object
    end

    define_method(:message) do
        cls['message']
    end

    define_method(:code) do
        cls['code']
    end
})
end
```

**What I tried**

I tried to create a .rb file basically copying the class factory script. And use `eval` method to eval it in runtime, but it seems I can pass in variables into the script

`eval File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'evals', 'error_class_generator.rb'))`

What should I do?

Comment: Put your class factory in a module and mix that module in to the classes that need the generation.

Comment: Drop the YAML approach, make proper classes. Easier to test, easier to read, self contained, less headache.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the effort of avoiding to repeat yourself at all costs, but I find your code quite complex for the problem you're trying to solve, namely send errors to your app users.

How about sticking to the a simpler `< MyAppError` inheritance hierarchy to avoid the duplicated code?

```
class MyAppError < StandardError
  attr_reader :object

  def message(message)
    # does stuff
  end

  def code(code)
    # also does stuff
  end
end

class ChatPolicyError < MyAppError
  def message(message)
    '[CHAT POLICY]' + super
  end
end

class UserBlacklisted < ChatPolicyError
  def message(message)
    # Does stuff too

    super
  end
end

[...] # You get the idea
```